# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Select Month"

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I was trying to develop a calendar app in java swing. I have 3 JComboBoxes, where you can select the year, month and day, and I keep getting this error every time I try to select a year:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Select Month"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at calendar.Show$1.itemStateChanged(Show.java:315)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1227)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1279)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1335)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:123)
    //......//
```

I think think the problem is in this part of my code:

```
jcbyear3.addItemListener (new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
                int y = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(arg0.getItem())); 
                //String mont= String.valueOf(monthjcb.getSelectedItem());
               
                String monthin = String.valueOf(monthjcb.getSelectedItem());
                String mont = monthin == null || monthin.isEmpty() || monthin.equals("Select Month") ? "January" : monthin;
                    
                    
                //int d=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dayjcb.getSelectedItem()));
                    
                String dayin = String.valueOf(monthjcb.getSelectedItem());
                int d = dayin == null || dayin.isEmpty() || dayin.equals("Select Day") ? 1 :Integer.parseInt(dayin) ;
             
                    
                
                int m=0;
                if(mont.equals("January")) {
                    m=1;
                }
                else if(mont.equals("February")) {
                    m=2;
                }
                //.....//

                String[] h=store.search(y, m, d);
                if(h[0].equals("0"))
                    dayarea.setText("No events found");
                else if(h[0].equals("1")){
                    dayarea.setText(h[1]);
                }
                else if(h[0].equals("2")){
                    dayarea.setText(h[1]+"\n"+h[2]);
                }
                else if(h[0].equals("3")){
                    dayarea.setText(h[1]+"\n"+h[2]+"\n"+h[3]);
                }
                else {
                    dayarea.setText(h[1]+"\n"+h[2]+"\n"+h[3]+"\n"+h[4]+"\n"+h[5]);
                }
                
            }
        });
```

Could someone please help me to correct my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
 String monthin = String.valueOf(monthjcb.getSelectedItem());
```

is returning you `"Select Month"`

then for the day you are asking again for the same *stuff* (*i.e.,* `monthjcb.getSelectedItem()`):

```
String dayin = String.valueOf(monthjcb.getSelectedItem());
```

so dayin = `"Select Month"` and because of that you will reach in the conditional:

```
int d = dayin == null || dayin.isEmpty() || dayin.equals("Select Day") ? 1 :Integer.parseInt(dayin) ;
```

this part `Integer.parseInt(dayin)`

leading to  `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “Select Month”` since you are trying to extract an Integer from a String that does not contain a number value encoded.

Base on your commented out line, I would say that instead of:

```
String dayin = String.valueOf(monthjcb.getSelectedItem());
```

you probably want:

```
String dayin = String.valueOf(dayjcb.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)